# Pinescript TradingView Backtesting Strategy Not Producing any Data

Tags: pine-script

Strategy Summary:

1. Trigger a SHORT position in a specific stock using the 15' timeframe.
2. Trade trigger price is the low of the final 15' candle of the premarket, minus another 10
   cents.
3. Trade can only trigger during the first 15 minutes of the new trading day (0930-0945 EST).
4. Once the short position is triggered I want to exit the trade when price moves downward for
   an additional $0.80 (profit target) from trigger price OR price moves upward $0.40 (stop-
   loss) from the trigger price.

Below is the code I have written, it currently does not produce any data.
I'm new to Pinescript and any help getting this formatted correctly and working would be greatly appreciated!

```
//@version=4

strategy("Closing Range Breakdown")

//I want the lowest price from this time period.
lastPremarketCandle = time(timeframe.period, "0915-0930:23456")

//I only want a trade to trigger short during the first 15 minutes of the trading day.
firstFifteenMinutes = time(timeframe.period, "0930-0945:23456")

//grabbing the low price of the last 15 minute candle of the premarket.
lowestValue = lastPremarketCandle ? low : na

//I want to be triggered into the trade 10 cents below the low of the lastPremarketCandle once the market is open.
tradeTriggerPrice = lowestValue - 0.10

//Here I'm creating a stop loss as well as a profit target.
profitTarget = tradeTriggerPrice - 0.80
stopLoss = tradeTriggerPrice + 0.40

//I want my backtest to cover this period of time.
var start = timestamp(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0)
var end = timestamp(2021, 3, 31, 0, 0)

//checking conditions to make sure we are backtesting the right time frame and incorporating the right price levels
if (time >= start and time <= end and firstFifteenMinutes)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 1250, when = tradeTriggerPrice)

//closing out the position if we hit the stop loss or the take profit target
strategy.close("closePosition", when = stopLoss or profitTarget)
```

Comment: You're calling `lowest` on a time, `lastPreMarketCandle`. Keep the reference and documentation open so you can read the function definitions as you use them, it will help immensely. Also assuming you're on the fifteen minute char you would use 'low' not `lowest`. Potentially `lowestValue = lastPremarketCandle ? low : na`. You also need to read about the var keyword and when it is necessary, this code seems to make a lot of guesses about how things work, so I would suggest re-reading the documentation and see how far that gets you.

Comment: @bajaco Thank you so much for the feedback...I updated my code block to reflect your suggestion. I will reread the documentation to figure out why it still produces no data. Cheers!

Comment: @AnyDozer thanks for the edit....hope this helps get a few more eyes on my problem, cheers!

Comment: @bajaco I've been in the documentation this morning and I'm just a bit stuck. Any chance you can offer additional assistance? Within my if statement I'm including my variable named 'firstFifteenMinutes' and wanting to check if this is true. I'm concerned that Pinescript doesn't allow me to check this as a bool. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I will take a look soon when I have time. Open your data window and add `plotchar(firstFifteenMinutes ? 1 : 0, 'Test First Fifteen Minutes', '')` and see if the value changes at the right time.

Comment: @bajaco Thank you so much, I'll will add this line and let you know what happens.

Comment: @bajaco I added the line and nothing happened. It's still reporting no data.